# How to show/hide fields based on visitor's country?

Tags: 7, entities, location

I have two fields (consider field_A, field_B). Anyone should see only one of these 2 fields based on their IP address:

- If users from US access the page, only field_A should be visible.
- For other countries, field_B should be visible.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I update my answer, take a look

Comment: Both answers works for me. Don't know which is better approach. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I include his answer in my alternative solution with implementation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of **Geo Ip** to do this. Install **Geo Ip** by following the instruction mentioned in the link http://www.beginninglinux.com/home/php/ubuntu-php-5-geo-ip

Make use drupal [ip_address()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/ip_address/7) function to get user ip address.

```
function test() {
  $code = geoip_country_code_by_name($ip);
  if ($code == 'US') {
    //hide  field B
  }
  else {
    //hide field A
  }

}
```

**geoip_country_code_by_name** returns country code. I think this approach gives you solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want show and hide your field according to country that detected by user IP first you should use a module that detect user country (like [ip2country](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip2country) module) and if it have javascript API to detect IP use it else where  in `hook_form_alter` detect country and hide field something like

```
function yourmoudle_form_alter(&$form,$form_state,$form_id){
 if($form_id=='your_form_id'){
     $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      $country_code = ip2country_get_country($ip);
    if($country=='US'){
     hide($form['field_b']);
   }
  }
}
```

**Alternative Solution**
Also you can handle it without module and use Geo IP 
and as @Vamsi suggest you can

> Install **Geo Ip** by following the instruction mentioned in the link
>   http://www.beginninglinux.com/home/php/ubuntu-php-5-geo-ip Make use
>   drupal [ip_address()](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) function to get user ip address.

[geoip_country_code_by_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php)  **return**  Returns the two letter ISO country code on success, or FALSE if the address cannot be found in the database.

```
function yourmoudle_form_alter(&$form,$form_state,$form_id){
 if($form_id=='your_form_id'){
     $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      $country_code = geoip_country_code_by_name($ip);
    if($country=='US'){
     hide($form['field_b']);
   }
  }
}
```